# Wordpress filter get_the_content()

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

I'm writing a plugin that requires adding to the content; adding a filter to the_content() is straightforward enough, but the theme I'm testing in uses get_the_content() to build the page.
There's an indication that it should be possible in the Wordpress codex but I don't understand the example:

If you use plugins that filter content (add_filter('the_content')), then this will not apply the filters, unless you call it this way (using apply_filters):

`apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file ))`

Can anyone help / explain?

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 1):

What they're saying is you'd have to add code to the place that `get_the_content()` is called.  From your description, that's in the theme - you'd have to change the theme's `get_the_content()` call as described.

The reason for that is that there are no filters in the `get_the_content()` function that you can hook into with your plugin (have a look at [the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L216) - there are no calls to the `apply_filters()` function in `get_the_content()`, except one for the "more" link text).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here it goes:

In your *functions.php* you can add something like this:

```
function do_filter_stuff($content) {
    //Whatever you want to do with your content
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_filter_stuff' );
```

Next, in your *page.php* (or whichever template you want to use it in) you can call the raw content with the same filter as following:

```
<?php echo do_filter_stuff(get_the_content()); ?>
```

Comment: Why do you add a filter in the first place, when you're calling the filter function directly? And if you're able to change the template, you don' need a filter at all.

Comment: Because according to the codex: "An important difference from the_content() is that get_the_content() does not pass the content through the the_content filter. This means that get_the_content() will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things." https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: Ah, I get the idea now: When `the_content()` is used in the theme, the filter is used. For all occurrences of `get_the_content()` you're calling the filter function by hand. (Of course you still have to use a child theme and could replace all calls of `the_content()`, too. Which would IMHO be more consistent.)